# Android Image display in RGB888 format

Tags: android, image, bitmap, rgb

I have decompressed jpeg image data in a byte array in RGB888 format. Bitmap configuration in android does not support RGB888. What should I do to display the image in imageview.

Comment: Try using the `ARGB8888`. It will *probably* work

Comment: I tried adding an alpha channel. But the image is not displayed properly, actual color is not shown.